# Kotlin: can I create an instance of a class in another class declaration (create object as class argument)?

Tags: kotlin, oop, solid-principles

Is it allowed to create an instance of a class in Kotlin inside another class, as an argument?

I'm  new to Kotlin and I need to implenet  the Single Responsibility Principle of SOLID Principles to this data class `Order`:

```
data class Order(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    // ... other properties. 
)
```

Instead of creating a single class with `notificationSender` and `invoiceGenerator` methods,
I have  two other classes, `OrderNotificationSender` and `OrderInvoiceGenerator`, to declare differente responsibilities, according to the SOLID principle:

```
class OrderNotificationSender {

    fun sendNotification(order: Order) {
        // send order notifications
    }
}

class OrderInvoiceGenerator {

    fun generateInvoice(order: Order) {
        // generate invoice
    }
}
```

As I followed a tutorial to create this code, my doubt if it is allowed to declare `OrderNotificationSender` and `OrderInvoiceGenerator` as `HandleOrder` arguments, like this:

```
    class HandleOrder(
    private val orderNotificationSender: OrderNotificationSender,
    private val orderInvoiceGenerator: OrderInvoiceGenerator) 
    {

        fun sendNotification(order: Order) {
            orderNotificationSender.sendNotification(order)
        }

        fun generateInvoice(order: Order) {
            orderInvoiceGenerator.generateInvoice(order)
        }
    }
```

If this is allowed, what is this called in Kotlin? I don't remember seeing this approach in other programming languages.

Comment: Sure you can do that. It's a bit like a builder pattern and a form of dependency injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your primary constructor's parameters to also be properties. This is  Kotlin syntactic sugar for the dependency injection pattern. In languages that don't have this feature, you would have to initialize your properties with the constructor parameter values, like this:

```
class HandleOrder(
    orderNotificationSender: OrderNotificationSender,
    orderInvoiceGenerator: OrderInvoiceGenerator
){

    private val orderNotificationSender: OrderNotificationSender = orderNotificationSender
    private val orderInvoiceGenerator: OrderInvoiceGenerator = orderInvoiceGenerator

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed. I guess it's called constructor parameters/arguments.

`class HandleOrder(val myObject: MyOwnType)` and `class HandleOrder(val myString: String)` are basically the same.